# Return in one string the min, max, average, sum, count of salaries with Stream and java8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a `List` of employees which are characterized by a salary. 
Why this code does not work?

```
String joined = employees.stream().collect(
    Collectors.summingInt(Employee::getSalary),
    Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getSalary)),
    Collectors.minBy(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getSalary)),
    Collectors.averagingLong((Employee e) ->e.getSalary() * 2),
    Collectors.counting(),
    Collectors.joining(", "));
```

I'm using a suite of collectors.

Comment: There is no such method that takes in multiple collectors like you're trying to do - you likely have a compile error. Spend some time reading [this streams tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2-2227132.html)

Comment: While I answered, I had to guess what exactly do you want to get. Your question would be more clear had you supplied the desired result example.

Comment: As a side note, it’s nonsensical to use `Collectors.counting()` when your source is a `List` you can simply call `size()` and save CPU cycles with the current (Java 8) implementation…

Comment: @Holger, `counting()` collector will unlikely to be improved even in future Java versions (unlike `count()` method). Even assuming [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8072840) questionable feature will be implemented, collector cannot say to the stream that you don't need to iterate the input.

Comment: @Holger, well to be precise it *will* be [improved](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/rev/1edfa4abd77a) to avoid unnecessary boxing, but it will still be O(n).

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: I can’t predict how likely it is for Oracle’s reference implementation, however, it’s not that hard to make that improvement even without changing the API. The point is that both, `Collectors` and the `Stream` implementation reside within the same library, even within the same package. There can be any off-API communication the developers want. After all, the only thing needed is the `Stream` implementation to recognize that the specified collector is the counting collector… But anyway, the original statement holds, using `List.size()` is preferable over `Collectors.counting()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that currently you're trying to get not the max/min salary, but the Employee having such salary. If you actually want to have the max/min salary itself (number), then these characteristics could be calculated at once using `Collectors.summarizingInt()`:

```
IntSummaryStatistics stats = employees.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Employee::getSalary));
```

If you want to join them to string, you may use:

```
String statsString = Stream.of(stats.getSum(), stats.getMax(), stats.getMin(), 
                               stats.getAverage()*2, stats.getCount())
                           .map(Object::toString)
                           .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

---

If you actually want to get an Employee with max/min salary, here `IntSummaryStatistics` will not help you. However you may create the stream of collectors instead:

```
String result = Stream.<Collector<Employee,?,?>>of(
            Collectors.summingInt(Employee::getSalary),
            Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getSalary)),
            Collectors.minBy(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getSalary)),
            Collectors.averagingLong((Employee e) ->e.getSalary() * 2),
            Collectors.counting())
        .map(collector -> employees.stream().collect(collector))
        .map(Object::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Note that in this way you will have an output like (depending on the `Employee.toString()` implementation:

```
1121, Optional[Employee [salary=1000]], Optional[Employee [salary=1]], 560.5, 4
```

Don't forget that `maxBy`/`minBy` return `Optional`.

---

If you are unsatisfied with the first solution and for some reason don't want to iterate the input several times, you can create a combined collector using a method like this:

```
/**
 * Returns a collector which joins the results of supplied collectors
 * into the single string using the supplied delimiter.
 */
@SafeVarargs
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, String> joining(CharSequence delimiter, 
        Collector<T, ?, ?>... collectors) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Collector<T, Object, Object>[] cs = (Collector<T, Object, Object>[]) collectors;
    return Collector.<T, Object[], String>of(
        () -> Stream.of(cs).map(c -> c.supplier().get()).toArray(), 
        (acc, t) -> IntStream.range(0, acc.length)
            .forEach(idx -> cs[idx].accumulator().accept(acc[idx], t)), 
        (acc1, acc2) -> IntStream.range(0, acc1.length)
            .mapToObj(idx -> cs[idx].combiner().apply(acc1[idx], acc2[idx]))
            .toArray(), 
        acc -> IntStream.range(0, acc.length)
            .mapToObj(idx -> cs[idx].finisher().apply(acc[idx]).toString())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(delimiter)));
}
```

Having such method you can write

```
String stats = employees.stream().collect(joining(", ",
        Collectors.summingInt(Employee::getSalary),
        Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getSalary)),
        Collectors.minBy(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getSalary)),
        Collectors.averagingLong((Employee e) ->e.getSalary() * 2),
        Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: I think, the output of `IntSummaryStatistics`’ `toString()` method is more useful than the `statsString`. It doesn’t double the average though, but why would you double the average anyway…

Comment: @Holger, probably so. The question is really weird.

Comment: Thank you for answering @TagirValeev.. you resolved the problem 
partially. In fact, what i want is to return the max,min,count,average and sum in one string and in one line. it should start like this: String joined = employees.stream(). /*...other method*/ . By the way sorry for the weird question, i posted it at 03:00 AM

Comment: @MohamedAzizBessrour, I added one more solution.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution.. Thanks for trying guys

```
String s = employees.stream().mapToDouble(a>a.getSalary()).summaryStatistics().toString();
```

and this is the output:

```
 DoubleSummaryStatistics{count=21, sum=17200,000000, min=100,000000,
 average=819,047619, max=2100,000000}
```

Comment: Note that your solution solves the different problem. At least what about multiplying the average by 2?

Answer (score 0):

We can use the below solution if we want to find only the sum of all salaries.

```
Integer a= emp.stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(Employe::getSalary));
```